# How can the endogeneity occur if the assumption E(Y|X)=0 assumption is satisfied?

Tags: least-squares, endogeneity

According to the assumption of OLS, x and error term is expected to be independent. However, I am wondering given the E(Y|X)=0 assumption is satisfied, how can x and error term be correlated?

Suppose the true f is y=x1+x2, and I intentionally left the x2. In this case, the population regression line that meets all other assumptions, which is y=2*x1, automatically satisfies the independent relationship assumption between x and error term.

Can anyone give me an example where these two situations happen simultaneously? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would the population line excluding x2 be y=2*x1?

Comment: Since it intentionally made the underfit mistake by omitting a variable that perfectly correlates to another variable retained in the model. The point is that this misspecified population line can also meet all the assumptions even though it omits an important variable.

Comment: You never said x1 and x2 were perfectly correlated. If they are, then the population design matrix is not full rank anyway and many combinations of coefficients describe the population relationship equally, including the one you proposed (i.e., {2, 0}). Also, if you're trying to understand a basic econometric result, using a pathological example may not be the best way to do so.

Comment: Got it, thank you Noah!